# i can't get some css properity from another file

Tags: php, css

Like the title said i can get some css property from another file.

I just can get at the final of this.

```
    .mylogo{
      position: relative;
      background: #525252;
    }

    .mylogo label{
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
      display: block;
      font-size: 40px;
      line-height: 50px;
      -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: 0.5s;
      -o-transition: 0.5s;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .tablecontent{
        width: 85%;
        top: 66px;
        left: 8%;
    }
```

But copy an paste (into the php/html file) the other part of this css file it work perfectly fine...

This is the other parth:

```
    .succesregisterwindow a{
      color: gray;
      font-family: cursive;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .succesregisterwindow a:hover{
      cursor:pointer;
    }

    .contentsuccesregisterwindow{
      opacity:0;  
      z-index: 2;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      pointer-events: none;
      transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }

    .contentsuccesregisterwindow:target{
      opacity:1;
      pointer-events: all;
      display:initial;
      transition: all ease-in 0.5s;
    }

    .succesregisterwindow{
      margin:auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color:rgba(226, 222, 222, 1);
      border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9);
      display: inherit;
      width: 500px;
      height: 140px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

And when i saw the network properity of the browser it show me only the first part of the file.

-im using sumble text 3.
-this work perfectly on firefox but not in google chrome.

Comment: Gonna need more info. What are the file names? What code is in what file? Post the entire file so we can look at it.

Comment: the file iname is mystyle.css the code is the code that i posted. Is just an css that i can't find that work with firefox but isnt work in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Wow something from another universe happened now, this css work perfectly now nad i didn't anything i just wnet to cocking the rice and it fixed WOW anyway i was using xampp if you want to share your knowledged about what the error can be